# Displaying database items in multirow dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making an "add edit" button for a post and I want to use the same view file.

The data is submitted but I am unable to load that data in edit-view. There is a dropdown which is called from another table and of its list saved in my main table.

My controller:

```
function addedit($order_id = ''){ 
    if(!empty($order_id)){
        $data['order_id'] = $order_id;
        $data['order'] = $this->som->getOrders(array('order_id'=>$order_id));    


       $prodList[''] = '--Select--';
       foreach($products as $prod){
           $prodList[$prod['product_id']] = $prod['product_name'];
       }
       $data['products'] = $prodList;
       $data['odrpdts'] = $this->som->getOrderProducts($order_id);
    }



      $data['stores'] = form_dropdown('from_store_name',getStores(),$data['order_id']['stores'],'class="form-control" id = "from_store_name"');
    $data['to_stores'] = form_dropdown('to_store_name',getStores(),'','class="form-control" id = "to_store_name"'); 



   $this->load->view('vendor/add_edit_vsorder',$data); 
}
```

My View:

```
<?php echo $stores;?>

<td ><?php echo form_dropdown("product[$r][product]",getAllProducts(),'',"class='form-control pc' rwcnt = '$r' id = 'product-$r'"); ?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the following Here's [a link](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model).

After reviewing the above link apply it in your codeigniter model (MY_Model) then you will be able to populate a drop down values easily like below.

```
public function payment()
{
    $this->load->model(['settings/payment_model']);
    $data['payment'] = $this->payment_model->fields('payment_method_id,payment_method_name')->as_dropdown('payment_method_name')->get_all();
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->load->view('Passenger/payment', $this->data);
}
```

then in the view file you will populate your drop-down or multi-row drop-down data as follows

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Payment Method</label>
        <select name="payment_m">
            <?php
               foreach($payment as $pay) {
                   echo $pay;
                }
            ?>
         </select>
</div>
```